# How to display multiple consecutive html elements

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm using ACF on my wordpress site to display HTML text in the search bar next to post titles based on that posts array values.

Right now the script only displays up to 1 of the html values, but I want it to include all of the values if they exist.

```
add_filter( 'asp_results', 'asp_custom_field_to_results', 10, 1 ); 
function asp_custom_field_to_results( $results ) {
  $custom_field = 'trade_status'; 

  foreach ($results as $k=>&$r) {
    if ($r->content_type != 'pagepost') continue;
    if ( function_exists('get_field') )
        $trade_status  = get_field( $custom_field, $r->id, true ); // ACF support
    else
        $trade_status  = get_post_meta( $r->id, $custom_field, true );
    // Modify the post title to add the meta value
    if ( !empty($trade_status) ) {
      if ( in_array('30', $trade_status) ) {
        $html = '<span class="new">New</span>';
      } else if ( in_array('20', $trade_status) ) {
        $html = '<span class="active">Active</span>';
      } else if ( in_array('10', $trade_status) ) {
        $html = '<span class="closed">Closed</span>';
      } else {
        $html = '';
      }
      $r->title = $html . $r->title;
    }
  }

  return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks like right now you're overwriting the value of $html for each matching iteration in the loop.  My guess is that you'd want to concatenate (.=) rather than overwrite (=) when you're doing this.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like when I replace the 4 instances of $html = with $html .= the script loops, and it continues adding more html (i.e. there was 'New' written once for first 'new', then twice for the next, three times next, etc.).